# Logic for AddWorkingDays to Date

Tags: c#, datetime

I have seen numerous posts related to adding working days (excluding weekends) to a date parameter and I tried using a few from those. However, all the solutions I picked are failing in some scenarios. 
below is the code I'm currently using:

```
private DateTime AddWorkingDays(DateTime dateValue, int noOfDays) 
    {
        // determine if we are adding or subtracting the days
        int nDirection = noOfDays < 0 ? -1 : 1;

        // move ahead the day of week
        int nWeekday = noOfDays % 5;
        while (nWeekday != 0)
        {
            dateValue = dateValue.AddDays(nDirection);
            if (dateValue.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday
                && dateValue.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            {
                nWeekday -= nDirection;
            }
        }

        // move ahead the number of weeks
        int nDayweek = (noOfDays / 5) * 7;
        dateValue = dateValue.AddDays(nDayweek);

        return dateValue;
    }
```

Example scenarios that fail: 
Date: 24 Nov, 2012(saturday), No of days: 5 (or 10)
Result: 1 Dec, 2012 (or 8 Dec, 2012) when the expected result was 30 Nov, 2012
Fails for 25 Nov, 2012 also.. and similar scenarios I guess, where the input date falls on a weekend.

Can someone please help fixing such scenarios ? Or provide a better solution ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This implementation (actually quite similar to yours) gives the results you expect:

```
    public static DateTime AddWorkingDays(this DateTime date, int days)
    {
        if (days == 0)
            return date;
        int sign = days < 0 ? -1 : 1;
        while (days % 5 != 0 || !date.IsWorkingDay())
        {
            date = date.AddDays(sign);
            if (!date.IsWorkingDay())
                continue;
            days -= sign;
        }
        int nWeekEnds = days / 5;
        DateTime result = date.AddDays(days + nWeekEnds * 2);
        return result;
    }

    public static bool IsWorkingDay(this DateTime date)
    {
        return !(date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas, I have a pretty basic (or dumb :)) question. How do I use the custom function IsWorkingDay with the DateTime attribute? do I have to define these methods in a static class and use it in my code?

Comment: You have to implement them as extension methods.

Comment: @CrazyFrog, they're [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx), so yes, you need to put them in a static class. Then you can just call `theDate.AddWorkingDays(5)` (make sure you import the namespace where the extension methods are declared)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you want to do is add a day to your `startDate`, as long as there are `noOfDays` left. Essentially, all that really means is that we need some sort of a counter, which doesn't increment if the day is a weekend. If we apply that logic, it becomes really simple:

```
    public static DateTime AddWorkingDays(DateTime startDate, int amount)
    {
        // It really is that simple!
        if (amount <= 0)
            return startDate;

        var ret = startDate;

        for (int i = 0; i < amount; )
        {
            var nextDay = ret.AddDays(1);

            // If it's saturday or sunday, just add it, but don't increment i. That way we'll
            // just keep going and virtually "skipping" the weekends.
            if (nextDay.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || nextDay.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            {
                ret = ret.AddDays(1);
                continue;
            }

            ret = ret.AddDays(1);
            i++;
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

Basically, all the code does is take the start date you provide, and the number of days you want to add. It takes that, and loops until it's run out of days to add. If it hits a day in the weekend, it simply doesn't increment `i`, effectively just ignoring those days. You may need to make some slight adjustments if you want the current day (if a working day) to count towards the total amount of working days too, but other than that this should work like you describe.

Comment: Thank you aevitas, I'm using the code provided by Thomas because I have to implement both addition and subtraction and it's close to the implementation i'm currently using